# How do I mount a sparse disk image permanently?

Tags: macos, mount, automount, disk-image

On Mac OS X 10.6.7, when I mount a sparse disk image (either by double-clicking it or using `hdid` from the command line), the image:

- Appears on my desktop
- Needs to be re-mounted every time I log in

I'd like to set up the equivalent of an `/etc/fstab` which will mount the image when the system boots, and make it permanent - so I don't have to worry if my symbolic links will resolve or not.

Is this more trouble than it's worth on a Mac? I noticed that there is no `/etc/fstab`, and `/etc/fstab.hd` contains a dire warning:

```
IGNORE THIS FILE.
This file does nothing, contains no useful data, and might go away in
future releases.  Do not depend on this file or its contents.
```

I tried `sudo hdid -notremovable <image>`, which seemed like half of what I wanted (according to `man hdid`), but it failed with an error: `hdid: attach failed - no mountable file systems`.

Comment: When you add `-nomount`, you at least get a device. But I haven't been able to mount that yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `attach failed - no mountable file systems` error seems to be a known bug of the `-notremovable` option to the `hdid` or `hdiutil` command respectively (see "hdituil -notremovable fails to mount disk image", https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2639671).

As a workaround, try adding your sparse disk image to `System Preferences -> User Accounts -> Log in Items`.

Yet another approach would be to write a launch daemon that mounts the sparse disk image at boot time (optionally for all users).

For a step-by-step guide in this respect see: http://wiki.ninjafocus.net/Mac_Mount_Points

Comment: Thanks for the links. Too bad the "Mac Mount Points" wiki solution only worked for 10.5. I guess I'll go with the "Log in Items" workaround for now.

Comment: +1 for launchd since you can control the mount to happen before a user logs in if desired.

Comment: The option System Preferences -> User Accounts -> Log in Items is now moved to System Settings -> General -> Login Items.
Add the disk image to Open at Login list.